# Excel counting taking into account adjacent cells (summing along a column, but looking across a row)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs, sumproduct

I have a table that tells me whether a value is found in a source:

([image of excel cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lON2M.png))

| Value | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| beta | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| gamma | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| delta | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| epsilon | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| zeta | 0 | 1 | 0 |

What I'd like to do is count the number of times that each source uniquely finds a given value.  For this example, there are:

- one value unique to Source1 (gamma)
- two values unique to Source2 (epsilon and zeta)
- zero values unique to Source3

In practice, this calculation will be used on ~10 columns and 1000s of rows, so I need some formula help.

I've tried various combinations of sumifs, countifs, sumproducts, and array formulas, but I am stumped by the fact that the sum needs to look perpendicularly to the column.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: But your example shows `Source3` have value for other values like `alpha`, `beta` so what will be result for them.

Comment: Can you show your expected result?

Comment: @Harun24HR, you correctly interpreted the expected results--one value per column--in this case, 0,1,2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With <kbd>Excel365</kbd> you can try below formula-

```
=SUM(--(MMULT($B$2:$D$7,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($B$2:$D$2),,,0))*(B$2:B$7)=1))
```

For `Non365` version of excel you try below array (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)  formula. In this case you must enter same number of one `1` of source column.

```
=SUM(--(MMULT($B$2:$D$7,TRANSPOSE({1,1,1}))*(B$2:B$7)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was after.  I had not considered matrix multiplication, and `SEQUENCE` is new to me (but that shouldn't have stopped me, as your array formula shows.  Thanks!!!